# Combining title across mfrow in R

Tags: r, histogram, title

I would like the title to be centered above the two plots in my mfrow object. Indeed, I have just that working, but the title is too far above the plots, and is only half included because of this. Below is my code showing the issue. How can I move the title down to just above the plots in the center?

```
a=1
p = c(rnorm(1000,5,10))
l = c(rnorm(1000,10,5))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(p,main=NULL)
hist(l,main=NULL)
title(main=print(paste0("Histogram a=", a)),outer=T)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set the `line` parameter in the `title` call to, for example, `-2`, you can place the title closer to the histograms:

```
a=1
p = c(rnorm(1000,5,10))
l = c(rnorm(1000,10,5))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(p,main=NULL)
hist(l,main=NULL)
title(main=print(paste0("Histogram a=", a)),outer=T, line=-2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could also do this with an outside margin, `par(mfrow=c(1,2),oma=c(0,0,2,0))`.  Results are identical in this case, though.

Comment: @user295691, yes that's right ! and you can even do both : define `oma` and then adjust the title to exactly where you want it with `line`...